# find maximum in arbitrary expression tree

Tags: mathematical-optimization, dsl, expression-trees, symbolic-math, nonlinear-optimization

I have a very simple language that gets compiled to an Expression tree, and then evaluated. Users can define mathematical operations, use variables and control flow. Moreover, from the script it's also possible to read an external input, which is fixed for a given evaluation (i.e. it outputs the same value if called repeatedly). For example this is a valid script:

```
if readInput() < 10 then
    x = 2 * readInput()
else
    x = 0
end
```

My problem: I need to compute the maximum and minimum value of `x`, for a given input domain, e.g. `[0, 1000]`.

Solutions I have thought of:

- assign to `readInput()` the boundaries of the domain and evaluate the values of `x`. It works in many cases but fails in many others, for example in the one above it evaluates to `x = 0` in both `0` and `1000`
- compute the max/min numerically, which would work in many cases but is compute intensive, and doesn't guarantee to reach the maximum, especially when there are discontinuities
- somehow convert the tree and use a symbolic math library to compute the boundaries

Are there any other alternatives that I'm missing?

***EDIT***

As suggested in the comments, this has been cross-posted to [CS StackExchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/158893/find-maximum-in-arbitrary-expression-tree)

Comment: it's not primarily about programming, you can try your luck on https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think this falls under the general heading of "static program analysis"; for questions about that, try cs.stackexchange.com. My advice is to look at the problem algebraically. I gather than Expressions can combine branching and arithmetic subexpressions. If so, you might try to state the max/min in terms of the branches and the max/min of the subexpressions. It will get more interesting when the branch tests involve computed values such as `x` here. Good luck and have fun.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/75574000/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/158893/755.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).  Please pick one site where you want this to appear.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it dynamically

```
max = -∞
...
if x > max then 
   max = x
...
```

at the end `max` holds the maximum value or -∞ if no value was input

Comment: Not sure I follow. Even if I have `max`, I still need to simulate the script evaluation with different values from the domain of the input, so don't really see how this helps

Comment: I assumed `x` is an integer. Is it a real number?